# Unable to find home page in joomla administrator

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am working on a joomla website. I have to do some modification in home page. I check in menu the page which is assigned as home page. But that page is not found in articles section. I am not able to find out where that page is? Anybody please can tell me where I have to found apart from articles where I can find the home page. 
I am new to joomla and I check everywhere about home page. But I am unable to found it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Joomla Home Page

A home page won't necessarily feature an article. There are plenty of options of what it can display.
There are so many options, same as the various menu items you have from all the components installed in your site.

It can even be a home-page with no component content - consisting only from modules.

We can't tell you what is the case with your site - it could be possible if you share a link to it -.

In order to find out what's going on with your homepage, you have to examine your Home menu item (default menu item).

What type of menu item it is (and of which component), and which content item/(s) is ordered to display.

#### Some example of homepage menu items:

1. It can be an articles -> single article menu. In this case, see which article it links to. You will be able to see the article title in the relative field, or the article id in the menu item's url field below: something like: `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=XXX`, where XXX the article ID.
2. It can be an articles -> Featured Items. In this case, it will display a number of articles in a blog layout fashion, according to the settings defined in the menu item layout tab. Notice that it's a common practice for homepages to use a featured items menu item and set it to display 0 items. Then the home page, will only display any modules that are assigned to this menu item - see also number 4 below.
3. It can any other kind of menu item of another component. In this case you need to find which component, type of layout and items it is set to display from it's options. It may be needed to also review the necessary settings of that component. If it's for example a K2 categories menu item, then you might have to change settings in that Category in K2.
4. Another case: Some templates provide an option to hide the component output for home-page and only display modules. See in your template's settings if it has a such feature.

For 2 and 4: In the case you are only outputting modules content in the homepage, you need to identify which modules are being used, and edit those.